# No matching distribution found for vtk error

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, vtk

I tried to use `pip install vtk` but I faced an error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/piSTo.png

"ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vtk (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for vtk"

I tried:

1. Installing both 32-bit and 64-bit
2. Installing all versions of python from 3.5 to 3.8
3. Upgrading pip

and also used Anaconda, I installed it properly but still not working in python and is not identified in cmd by `vtk --version`.

Help me, please
Thanks

Comment: _also used Anaconda,I installed it properly but still not working..._ Please be more specific, you completely gloss over the specifics of how you tried to install it using Conda. You also haven’t told us much about your environment, I feel we’re missing a good amount of information.

Comment: I used     $conda install -c anaconda vtk     in Anaconda also add new PATHs. It takes some time and installed vtk properly I checked the version and everything was fine but just in Anaconda Prompt not in cmd or python.

Comment: Well are you sure the program was run using the right environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To update this answer VTK now has Python 3.8 support under the 9.0 version has just been released [VTK 9.0 download](https://vtk.org/download/#latest) if you download and install the whl from the link provided.

Answer (score 3):

[vtk 8.1.2](https://pypi.org/project/vtk/8.1.2/) was released at Nov 29, 2018. The release [provides](https://pypi.org/project/vtk/8.1.2/#files) a number of wheels but not for Python 3.8.

Use Python 3.7 (64-bit required). Or compile from [sources](https://vtk.org/download/).

Answer (score 1):

Installation on python 3.8 is successful using conda

```
conda install vtk
```

Answer (score 1):

Able to install vtk on python3.8 directly from the source. Follow below commands, it is a bit time taking to build the wheel but would definitely install vtk. Download the version you want to install, in my case i installed the latest 9.1.0 from https://vtk.org/download/

```
//extract the downloaded file.
mkdir VTK_BUILD
cd VTK_BUILD
cmake -GNinja -DVTK_WHEEL_BUILD=ON -DVTK_WRAP_PYTHON=ON {vtk source path}
ninja
python3 setup.py bdist_wheel
```

copy path to VTK_BUILD add vtk build paths to the bashrc file to set the path.

```
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:{copied build path}
    export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:{copied build path}
```

This should install vtk.

source link: https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/blob/master/Documentation/dev/build.md#building-vtk

Comment: My problem was solved. that was because of python and vtk versions